# What assumptions can be made using a $pV$ diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

[image]

In this question I am asked to find the volume of a gas at $V_3$

I have some parts that  am not clear on.

1. Is it reasonable to assume the temperature at $3$ is $657^{\circ}C$
2. Work is done by the system $2\to3$
3. The envoiroment does work from $3\to1$
4. When process $3\to1$ is complete the temprature returns to $37^{\circ}C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 & Q4: Points 2 and 3 are on the same line labeled isothermal, meaning same temperature

Q2 & Q3: The energy content of a gas is a function solely of its temperature (ideal gas!), i.e, if it drops in temperature, it has done work, or if it gains temperature, work has been done to it.

Hope this helps.